# Magisk: Failed to patch: Unsupported image format

Tags: rooting, magisk

I'm trying to root a Pixel 5a using Magisk (24.3).  I've downloaded the barbet-rd2a.211001.002-factory-dbed3a6f factory image, pushed it to the phone, and tried to patch it with Magisk.

However, the output shows an error:

```
- Device platform: arm64-v8a
- Installing: 24.3 (24300)
- Copying image to cache
- Unpacking boot image
! Unsupported/Unknown image format
! Installation failed
```

I gather that I've downloaded the wrong image.  How do I know which image is compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The factory images are provided by Google in ZIP format.  You have to unzip it, select the boot image, and **then** apply the Magisk patch.